# Does the $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{g(x)}{e^x}$ exist?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

Suppose for all real $x$ that $g^{(n)}(x) = g^{(n-1)}(x)$ and $g^{(n-1)}(0) = -1$ where $g^{n}(x)$ is the nth derivative. Does the $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{g(x)}{e^x}$ exist?

Isn't this answer just the form $g(x) = -e^x$? and Hence $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{g(x)}{e^x} = -1$? How could I more rigorously show this?

Comment: Is $n$ fixed or should $g$ be such that equalizes hold for arbitrary $n$?

Comment: $g$ should be fixed and hold for any arbitrary $n$

Comment: This holds for one fixed $n$?  I think $g(x)$ will be $-e^x$ plus a polynomial of degree $n-2$.  Thus your limit is $-1$.

Answer (score 1):

Weird.  Isn't that the function $h(x):= e^{-x}g(x)$ has null derivative?
Which implies $h$ is a constant function.
Is there any other constraint?

Comment: Why is it weird? Also, nice catch that we don't need general uniqueness theorem here.

Comment: Yeah. Because most of the time, for a similar problem, we can't calculate explicitly the formula of $g$.

Comment: I mean it asks if the limit exists ... I suppose you could prove it does not as well, but the question is worded exactly as given.

Comment: I just confirmed your thought that $g(x)=-e^{x}$

Answer (score 1):

The taylor series of a function is given as:
$$g(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{g^{(n)}(0)}{n!}x^n$$
so in your case:
$$g(x)=-\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!}=-e^x$$
so:
$$\frac{g(x)}{e^x}=-1$$
which is not dependent on $x$ and so converges for all $x$

Comment: Doesn't that require to prove that $g$ if analytical?